# Python Script Package not working on Atom. Any tips?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, atom-editor

So im attempting to run Python code on Atom using the well-known "script" package. However, when I press cmd+i to run the code, it executes but doesn't show anything in the terminal. It works perfectly fine with simpler code though

Refer to pics below:

[This is what appears when it works for super simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFku.png)

[This is what I get when I run longer code/projects..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZVH5.png)

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question and not as images. Check your code if it has something like `while True:`.

Comment: I get the same output if a run a code that makes a plot. Are you plotting something?

Comment: Not really, just a bunch of if statements and whatnot.. I would post the code but its for a school project so I wouldn't be allowed to :/